# Python 3 create package canonically without Internet

Tags: python-3.x, pip, packaging

I am in a non-internet connected (air gapped) environment.  I have access to the `python:latest` docker image:

```
root@dd8e38ac55dd:/# python -V
Python 3.11.4
root@dd8e38ac55dd:/# pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.1.2
setuptools 65.5.1
wheel      0.41.1
```

My understanding is that package generation in 2023 should not use a `setuptools` `setup.py`, and instead I should use a `pyproject.toml` (see: [setuptools Quick Start Guide](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) and [setuptools Build System Support](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/build_meta.html)).

The `setuptools` documentation says to setup `pyproject.toml` with:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

plus my package metadata needed for a package build. Great!  Then it says that I need to `pip install build`.  Huh?  Why is the tooling for the build using `setuptools` not in the package itself?

Ok, moving on...  I know I can try to use `pip wheel` to generate a package, and it supports `pyproject.toml`.  When I run it, I can make a package as long as I am internet connected, but as soon as I disallow my container internet access or run `pip` with `--no-index` the wheels fall off. Without the internet, `pip` complains that it cannot find or download/install `setuptools`.  This is very curious considering that as I showed above, both `setuptools` and `wheel` are both installed in the container already.

Is there no supported, canonical way to make a pure Python package for distribution/deployment using only the utilities in a standard Python install, specifically the official Python container image?

I have tried using `pip wheel` as opposed to PyPA `build` since I am in an environment that currently does not have it.  I expected that the official Python container image would have a built-in, batteries included method to build a package using `pyproject.toml` since that is the current package building recommendation. I am led to believe that using `setup.py` is still functional, but deprecated.  Is it my only way without bringing in another dependency or writing a build system into my package code?